# How to change values of combo after every new entry - Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to know how can I change values of combo box after every new entry in a Tkinter GUI?

SO below is the code where I am extracting values from a json file and showing it in a combo box. but I am also adding new values in the json file in the GUI but, I want to know how can I add new values to this combo box without opening the gui again in order to update the values. I want the values in combo to change immediately after a new entry is added into the json file.

```
coursefile = open('Course.json')
courserecord = json.load(coursefile)
coursenamerecord = []
for items in courserecord["COURSES"]:
    coursenamerecord.append(items["Course Name"])


coursenamelabel = Label(tab5, text='Course Name:', font=('Open Sans Semibold', 12))
coursenamelabel.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=175, sticky='e')
coursenameentry = ttk.Combobox(tab5, width= 66, value=(coursenamerecord))
coursenameentry.place(x= 475, y= 183)coursefile = open('Course.json')
```

Comment: there is a `ttk.Combobox.set` method you can use and also a way to execute a **function** by a binding or a button.

Comment: I don't understand how can I you give some link or code to figure out something. It's a request

Comment: Are you modifying the raw file or are modifying it through your GUI application?

Comment: So you want to modify the Combobox whenever there is a new element in the list?

Comment: I get the data from entry and I store that data in the JSON file. From that JSON file I get the values for the combo box. I can re run the python script to get the values in the combo box but I want the values to show immediately after I add the data in JSON file.

Comment: Yeah basically when I store the data in JSON file and that value should be immediately be displayed in combobox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you may use the `combobox.config()`. Get the users entry upon pressing a button, then append that value to a list and then reconfigure the value something like shown below
You may do something similar.

Here is an example

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def update():
   lst.append(entry.get())
   combo.configure(values=lst)

lst = ['Math', 'Science', 'Language']

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=var, values=lst)
combo.pack()

btn = Button(root, text='Update', command=update)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I will try this method and see if I can get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

So you have already stored the values in a list. Then get the value you need to store from the entry widget which you created in the last line(assuming the value u want to display inn combobox is getting from here). Append the list `coursenamerecord` with this value.

P.S.: Pls go through my profile to find a question "apply frame(in one file) to a root window(in another file)". I'd lov some explanatons there.

Comment: Hello. I have went through your profile and saw your question  so, you want to show a frame which you created in another file on you main file (I hope make it sense)?

Comment: absolutely yeah

Comment: Look I am not saying it's impossible but easy and efficient way to do this would be you create the frame in your main file and create functions in other file. Then you import the functions required to create the frame in main file. The reason I am saying is this because you have to specify place a frame will show so you have do quite .. complex (not really) coding to change that.